# How to slice or substring innerHTML of all elements' containing one class name with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I can shorten the innerHTML of an element selected by its Id using either slice or substring (I'm not sure of the difference between the two, but both do what I want) using this code:

```html
<p id="demo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
<p id="demo2" class="demo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```

```js
let text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.slice(0, 9);
```

which outputs as

```markdown
The quick
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

However, I can't get it to work on several elements containing the same class.
I have tried this:

```js
let text = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
for (let i=0; i < text.length; i++) { 
  text.innerHTML.slice(0, 9);
}
```

But on Codepen it just says "TypeError: elements.innerHTML is undefined".

What am I missing, please?

Comment: `text[i].innerHTML=text[i].innerHTML.slice(0, 9);`

Answer (score 4):

Using vanilla javascript you can't change all elements at once. Instead, you need to iterate through them. Furthermore, just calling `slice` on the `innerHTML` won't change it, you need to assign the value.

```
let texts = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
for (let i=0; i < texts.length; i++) { 
  texts[i].innerHTML = texts[i].innerHTML.slice(0, 9);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were iterating over an `HTMLCollection` without referencing the index: `text[i]`.

1. Modern JS tends to favour [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for element selection, and [then iterating over it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) with something like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement).
2. You should be targeting the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) of the element rather than its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).
3. Instead of `slice` I'd probably prefer [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get characters from a string.

##### `forEach`

```js
// Cache all the demo elements
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.demo'); 

// Loop over them, and update the textContent
els.forEach(el => {
  const text = el.textContent;
  el.textContent = text.substr(0, 9);
});
```

```html
<p class="demo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
<p class="demo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```

> [Note: There is no way to stop or break a `forEach` loop other than by throwing an exception.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description) If you need such behavior, the `forEach` method is the wrong tool.

There's also a compatibility issue with IE11 so here is `for...of` as @connexo suggested in the comments.

##### `for...of`

```js
// Cache all the demo elements
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.demo'); 

// Loop over them, and update the textContent
for (const el of els) {
  const text = el.textContent;
  el.textContent = text.substr(0, 9);
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
<p class="demo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```

Comment: It would be even more modern, readable and safer to iterate using `for (const el of els) { ... }` because it doesn't depend on whether the collection implements `forEach`. Apart from that, clearly the best answer so far.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` always has `forEach`. In fact, iirc, it's the only array method that it can use.

Comment: It does not, in IE 11. Even if that were not the case, using `for ... of` puts you on the more readable, safer side. It's also simpler because it doesn't require passing a callback.

Comment: Ha. Ok, fair point. I stopped developing for IE 15 years ago.

Comment: Even if you don't care about incompatibility, using `for...of` is cleaner, more readable and simpler.

Comment: I don't really have to care about incompatibility because the company I work for doesn't support IE11. And I'll have to disagree with you about `forEach`, not to be annoying, but sometimes code is a very personal choice. Thanks for the edit, btw. Hope your day is going well.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried @Andy's solution and it works. I've also modified it as @Connexo says, like this (I think): `const els = document.querySelectorAll('.demo'); for (const el of els) { let text = el.textContent;  el.textContent = text.substr(0, 9);};` and that works, too. Now to decide which version to use!

Comment: @Gillian Just decide based on what you consider easier to read and understand.

Comment: @connexo I added your suggestion to my answer. Hope that was ok. And I hadn't considered early termination of the loop which `forEach` doesn't provide.

Comment: Good decision. If you now change both `let` in  that example to `const`, you passed my code review :)

Comment: Haha, done @connexo

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
let text = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
for (let i=0; i < text.length; i++) { 
  text[i].innerHTML = text[i].innerHTML.slice(0, 9);
}
```